# The react component renders several times when using useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use functional react component with hooks.

```
const [loaded, setLoaded] = React.useState(null);
const [title, setTitle] = React.useState(title);

React.useEffect(() => {
    //...
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
          setLoaded(true);
          setTitle(title);
      });
}, []);
```

In this case, the component is rendered twice. On the one hand, it seems to be logical.

But I also have a checkbox handler in this component

```
const changeHandler = event => {
    //...
    setTotal(new_total);
    setError(false);
};
```

In this case, two rendering does not occur, although state also changes 2 times. I can’t understand why this is happening.

**P.S.**

There is no problem to solve this problem, I wonder why this is exactly what happens

**UPD**:

If I set in `useEffect`

```
setLoaded(true);
setTitle(title);
setTitle2(title);
setTitle3(title);
```

will be 4 re-renders, and if I set in `changeHandler`

```
setTotal(new_total);
setError(false);
setError2(false);
setError3(false);
```

will be 1 re-render

Comment: each of those function calls would be a state update, so each would need to re-render. why dont you just merge the state into an object? `const [state, setState] = React.useState({title: '', loaded: null});`

Comment: React batches `state` updates, that's why you only see one `re-render` when you call `changeHandler`. You see 2 `re-renders` when the component mounts because first `render` is the component and `useEffect` change the `state` only after the component mounts, so that's the second one

Comment: @AsafAviv please see the update

Comment: @ВладимирВладимирович does the answer below help? Would you like me to update it to show how `setError`, `setError2`, `setError3` can be achieved with the same pattern?

Comment: Are you sure that's the case? I'm setting two state variables inside `useEffect` and it only renders after the initial render: https://codesandbox.io/s/late-brook-vkc2s

Comment: @EvanTrimboli my code looks something like this https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-kepler-q7g51

Comment: That's interesting. This may be related: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14259

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> React wraps your event handlers in a call to
>   `unstable_batchedUpdates()`, so that your handler runs inside a
>   callback. Any state updates triggered inside that callback will be
>   batched. Any state updates triggered outside that callback will not be
>   batched. Timeouts, promises, and async functions will end up executing
>   outside that callback, and therefore not be batched.

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14259

Answer (score 2):

A side effect of calling setter method of the `useState()` hook, is that doing so triggers the component to re-render.

One solution to avoid the redundant re-render would be to merge your component state like this:

```
function functionalComponent() {

    /* Merge both values into common "state object */
    const [{ loaded, title }, setState] = React.useState({ 
        loaded : null, 
        title : "inital title" 
    });

    React.useEffect(() => {

        /* 
        Single call to setState triggers on re-render only. The
        value of "new title" for title could have been set in the
        inital state, however I set it here to show how combined
        state can be updated with a single call to setState()  
        */
        setState({ loaded : true, title : "new title" })

        /*
        setLoaded(true);
        setTitle(title);
        */
    }, []);

    /* Use loaded and title variables as needed during render */
    return <div>{ loaded } - { title }</div>
}
```

Comment: or better yet just on the initial state definition put the props.title in as the value, eliminating the need for another setState in useEffect :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell yes true - I just added that "new title" value to illustrate that method of tracking two state fields in a single state object